# How to handle list of forms in Vue JS

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-component

I have a list of forms and I want to bind them with a single `ref`.

The ref will hold an object with form number as keys and values should be again an object whose keys are be bound to the nested object keys.

```
const forms = reactive({})

// template 

<form v-for="item in list" :set="forms[item.id]={}">
  <input v-model="forms[item.id]['name']" />
  <input v-model="forms[item.id]['email']" />
  <input v-model="forms[item.id]['phone']" />
</form>
```

I have the above implementation but field refs don't seem to work, I can't either enter values in the fields.

A working [demo](https://play.vuejs.org/#eNqNUk1PAjEQ/Su1l9UE2SicyEKiBqMe1KiJB8phswxQ7FfaLpI0+9+ddgExMYTTtu+9efNmtoHeGNNd10AHtHCV5cYTB742I6a4NNp6EoiFOWnI3GpJMpRmTFVaOU/m2koyjPR5aC52qHSLLZg9gBCafGorZmcZCoq8bYHmePEgjSg94I2QYnk1CiEVN02R4y2iiUlt1pf4GTLKsYpwRSZXnetOb8ooGWBeJKJqEtkpdg8No1vb/ug+1g9ICJFN5v3EIcuVqT16Sz0D8cdkkqlSQoYN8lPEIEsuTlabpVYH3kUeSTwW+cFOaId6hyud80V35bTCPxTSTmilpeEC7IvxHFfOKA7XdmW0xI1/PyXM2xo6O7xaQvX1D75ym4gx+mrBgV0Do3vOl3YBvqXH78+wwfOexLlqgeoj5Bs4LeqYsZXd1mqGsQ90Ke1jemdcLT7ceONBud1QMWhUNknPKL69uyOj/8btdXupjqmGNj+CPfNq)

I want to be able to handle nested objects as refs to input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must initialize the ref first, shortcut initializations like v-const have only recently been introduced into the plan

```js
const list = ref( [1,2,3] )

watch(list, list => {
  list.forEach(item => form.value[item] = {})
}, { immediate: true })
```

Comment: The example in solution is not relevant but the idea is indeed correct and worked for me. 
Thanks.